# Why the stack trace contains repeat call to the parseInt() method?

Tags: java, string, exception, integer, parseint

I compiled the following code with JDK 11.0:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class inputWithScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name and roll number");
    String name = input.next();
    Integer rollNumber = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    input.close();
    if (name.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("oops! You didnt enter your name");
    if (rollNumber < 0)
        System.out.println("Enter a valid roll number");
    System.out.println("Hello "+name+" Roll Number   "+rollNumber);
```

and tested the program with the following input (mixed input for the rollNumber variable is deliberate):

```
Enter your name and roll number
Manraj 2018CSE1023
```

the compiler raises an exception: NumberFormatException with the stack trace as follows:

```
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at inputWithScanner.main(inputWithScanner.java:7)
```

The question is:
Why is there a repeated call for parseInt() method?

I tried same code with valueOf() method and executed the program with same input. The compiler raises the same exception, and  stack trace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2018CSE1023"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983)
        at inputWithScanner.main(inputWithScanner.java:7)
```

It shows that the valueOf() method calls parseInt() method. But Why parseInt() calls itself?

Comment: Hi, It's happening because `2018CSE1023` is not a valid number and to Fix this. You will need to store this variable as `String`

Comment: As I mentioned, the question is related to the stack trace, and not the error in this program. Input is deliberately given different from the expected.

Comment: When a method is overloaded, it is common to implement one overload as a call to another one.  This shows up in the stacktrace as two (or more) successive frames with the same method name.  But it is not the same method.

Answer (score 8):

`parseInt` is [defined](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b7c307c019a34db6a70a415caecd31101f8956cf/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L769) as

```
public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return parseInt(s,10); // this is line 770 currently
}
```

Then at line 652 (inside that inner call to `parseInt`) it throws an exception. At which point both the two-arguments `parseInt` and the one-argument one are in the stack trace.

In short, those are two different methods, one with one arguments that calls one with two.

`valueOf` is [defined](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b7c307c019a34db6a70a415caecd31101f8956cf/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L956) as

```
public static Integer valueOf(String s, int radix) throws NumberFormatException {
    return Integer.valueOf(parseInt(s,radix));
}
```

Which calls the version with two arguments directly.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks Federico.

Comment: Apparently, the stacktrace only shows the method name and its filename and line number, but not the *method signature*.